# Why can you assign a slice to an empty interface but not cast it to the same empty interface

Tags: go, slice

Why does golang not support casting a slice to an empty interface? You can however work around it, by declaring a variable with an empty interface as type and assinging the slice to that variable. Why are those not the same thing?

Example: https://play.golang.com/p/r4LXmR4JhF0

Comment: Go doesn't support casting _at all_.

Comment: You are type asserting, not casting. This is something _completely_ different. Please work through the Tour of Go once more for this type of basics. Your `slice` is not an interface type and this cannot by type asserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Go doesn't support casting *at all*.

There simply is no type casting in Go*.

What you're attempting to do is a type assertion.

There are two reasons your attempt fails. Both are explained by the compiler:

1. `invalid type assertion: slice.(<inter>) (non-interface type []interface {} on left)`

   You cannot type-assert any non-interface type to an interface.
2. `non-name *castedSlice on left side of :=`

   `*castedSlice` is invalid in this context.

Assignment is the correct approach if you want to store a slice in a variable of type `interface{}`.  You can do this a few ways:

1. As you have discovered, this works:

   ```golang
   var result interface{}
   result = slice
   ```
2. You can combine those two lines:

   ```golang
   var result interface{} = slice
   ```
3. You can also do a short variable declaration:

   ```golang
   result := interface{}{slice}
   ```

---

*lest anyone nitpick the statement: It is technically possible to accomplish the same as type casting in Go, with use of the unsafe package, but as this is outside of the language spec, and is, by definition, unsafe, I think it's still a reasonable statement that Go does not support type casting.

Comment: So if I get this correctly, what go's does is the following: it save some metadata about the underlying value in an interface{}. Because of that, it can assert that interface foo is "assignable" to type foobar? However, since a map is not an interface, it can not assert that?

Comment: I'm not sure how maps fit into this discussion, but you can only type assert _from_ an interface. This is explained in the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions), and also in [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15).